# Create Img tag from URL

Tags: php, regex, url, image, preg-replace

**What I want**

---

If the URL in the string contains a `.jpg` at the **end of the URL** (not the string) then it should make an image from it with `preg_replace` else make a normal link.

so for example:

If I have `http://www.example.com/images/photo.jpg` then it should replace with:

`<img src="http://www.example.com/images/photo.jpg" alt="http://www.example.com/images/photo.jpg">`

**The problem:**

---

The URL is replaced with a link in any way and my regex isn't working :( .

**What I have tried:**

---

```
        $content = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/[^\s]+(?=\.jpg))/i","<img src=\"$1\" alt = \"$1\"></img>",$content);    

        $content = nl2br(preg_replace("/(http:\/\/[^\s]+(?!\.jpg))/m", "<a href=\"$1\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"blank\" title=\"$1\" class=\"news-link\">$1</a>", $content));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function replace_links($content)
{
    if (preg_match('#(http://[^\s]+(?=\.(jpe?g|png|gif)))#i', $content))
    {
        $content = preg_replace('#(http://[^\s]+(?=\.(jpe?g|png|gif)))(\.(jpe?g|png|gif))#i', '<img src="$1.$2" alt="$1.$2" />', $content);
    }
    else
    {
        $content = preg_replace('#(http://[^\s]+(?!\.(jpe?g|png|gif)))#i', '<a href="$1" rel="nofollow" target="blank" title="$1" class="news-link">$1</a>', $content);
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer :), I've tried a similar solution with `IF/THEN`, but yours is better ;), it works, but there are 2 problems with it, 1. in this way I can't have any links which is not ending in `jpg`, `png` or `gif` in the `content`, the 2. is that after the photos there is the image type `.jpg` in plus so ends with `<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" alt="http://example.com/image.jpg">.jpg`, I don't need that and I don't know how to get rid of them as I see you've put a $2 in the source and alt, I've deleted them, than disappears but the image is not shown o.O

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = preg_replace('#\b(http://\S+\.jpg)\b#i', '<img src="$1" alt="$1" />', $content);
```

Comment: `\b` matches before/after periods and other symbols: so it would match `http://something.com/image.jpg.html` and the like. And don't you need to escape those backslashes?

Comment: same problem with Amargohosh's version.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lookaround. Just go with

```
$content = preg_replace("#(http://[^ ]+\\.jpg(?= |$)#i","<img src=\"$1\" alt=\"$1\"/>", $content);
```

Comment: If the image replacement is before the link replacement then shows it very badly, if its after the link replacement then it's just a link, what should I do?

Comment: this is what I get if the image replacement is before the link replacement: `http://192.168.2.104/images/users/image.jpg" alt = "" rel="nofollow" target="blank" title="http://192.168.2.104/images/users/image.jpg">" class="news-link">http://192.168.2.104/images/users/image.jpg">`

Answer (score 0):

I think you used the lookahead operator when you wanted lookbehind.  You could change `(?=\.jpg)` to `(?<=\.jpg)` but there are other, cleaner regex's I'm sure others will post.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$parse_img='Hello, http://orbitco-ccna-pastquestions.com/images/Q5.jpg
```

In the figure above, router R1 has two point-to-point . ';

```
$parse_img=preg_replace('/(https?:\/\/(.\*)?\\.jpg|png|gif)[\s+]*/i',"< img src=\"$1\" alt = \"$1\">< /img >",$parse_img);

echo $parse_img;
```

Suyash